# Cloning GitHub private repository with Docker container non-root user?

Tags: git, docker, ssh, npm

I am trying to install a private repository npm package via GitHub:

```
npm install --save-dev MyCompany/MyRepository#my-branch
```

It works well on my host system. However, we are using `docker-compose` to orchestrate all our Docker containers, especially our `node` one.

As our GitHub repository is a private one, I set up SSH agent forwarding as following (simplified) `docker-compose.yml` snippet shows:

```
version: '2'

services:
    node:
        build: docker/node
        environment:
            - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
        volumes:
            - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent
        user: "${UID}:${GID}"
```

We are using host UID and GID to prevent from some issues with file permissions. These variables are exported before launching the `docker-compose run` commands.

Yet, when we try to launch the install command from our container:

```
docker-compose run --rm --no-deps node bash -ci 'npm install'
```

We got a connectivity issue (`Error connecting to repository. Please, check the url.`).

We then tested directly a SSH connection:

```
docker-compose run --rm --no-deps node bash -ci 'ssh -T git@github.com'
```

And we now get an issue with SSH connection:

> No user exists for uid 1000

Is it related? I'm not sure.

One solution may be to create a dummy user with host UID before launching the command. Yet, how can I create it? I can't do it during build (as I don't have access to UID environment variable), and if I try when executing a command, I got:

```
docker-compose run --rm --no-deps node bash -ci "sudo"
sudo: unknown uid 1000: who are you?
```

Or is there any other solution?

Comment: "We are using host UID and GID to prevent from some issues with file permissions" can you give an example?

Comment: how does it behave without the `user: "${UID}:${GID}"` line?

Comment: Note that I wrote a blog post to detail this `${UID}:${GID}` part and the solution I found: https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2017/01/26/yarn-npm-install-within-docker-container.html

Answer (score 4):

I have finally succeeded in making it work. That's far from easy, but here is the solution.

First, I don't use my docker-compose container, but instead run a new one, based on my image. I kept the SSH agent share:

```
USER_ID=$(id -u)
docker run --rm -it \
    -v `pwd`:/app \
    -v $(SSH_AUTH_SOCK):/ssh_agent \
    -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh_agent \
    -e USER_ID=$USER_ID \
    my_project_node bash -ci "/app/bin/yarn.sh"
```

Note that I kept SSH agent sharing (the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` parts) and add an environment variable with host user UUID, as we need it to create our dummy user in container, to keep correct file permissions.

The `/app/bin/yarn.sh` file is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

useradd -u $USER_ID dummy
mkdir -p /home/dummy/.ssh /home/dummy/.npm
chown -R dummy /home/dummy
cat /app/docker/node/.ssh_config > /home/dummy/.ssh/config
su dummy -c 'npm install'
```

The trick here is to create a dummy user with same UUID than on the host system. Then, we add some required folders owned by dummy. We then add a `.ssh/config` file to prevent from GitHub host checking, which causes npm to fail. Its content is:

```
Host github.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

This solution is far from being trivial, and I am curious if any other developer has a better one. :)

Comment: I have a bit larger function doing the heavy lifting, it's not quite an answer, but more than will fit in this comment. Check it out https://github.com/tianon/gosu/issues/40#issuecomment-336324805 and see if there is anything that might improve your answer. There is also some discussion with the maintainer of gosu who also works on Docker there so some good tips and tricks.